# typeKeys not working in selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium-rc

I am writing [selenium tests](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) for input fields with jquery autocomplete.
I've got advise to use `typeKeys` method.
But it doesn't work:

```
var soda = require('soda')
  , assert = require('assert');

var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost'
  , port: 4444
  , url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia'
  , browser: 'firefox'
});

browser.session(function(err){
  browser.open('/', function(err, body, res){
    browser.typeKeys('searchInput', 'Hello', 
                 function(err, body, res){
      // browser.testComplete(function(){

      // });
    });
  });
});
```

Nothing appears in `searchInput` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 22 and 23 have problems with typeKeys (see [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5841) for example).

I reverted to FireFox 21 which works fine. You can download the en-US version [here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/21.0/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2021.0.exe). Alternatively you can use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and install it with

```
 cinst Firefox -Version 21.0
```

Don't forget to turn off automatic updates in the settings.

Alternatively you could try using `sendKeys` instead.